# How to hide the option in dropdownlist in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a dropdownlist and I need to hide one option based on the condition

Mycode is something like below :

```
 $scope.sqs.qs6_PropertyType.answer = _.findWhere($scope.propertyType, { id: '2' });
```

// this is to set the selected value to 2

I need to Hide the option with value="2" I have written something like below:

```
$("#qs6_PropertyType").children('option[value="2"]').hide();
```

I have tried like below as well but its not working

```
//var qs6obj = angular.element(document.querySelector('#qs6_PropertyType'))
                        //qs6obj.childElement.remove('option[id="2"]');
```

HTML :

```
<td class="cell">
                                <div data-dropdownlist-question=""
                                     data-ng-model="subject.sqs.qs6_PropertyType"
                                     data-question-attrs="{
                                        questionCell: { visible: false },
                                        answer: {
                                            items: propertyType,
                                            theme: 'native',
                                            style: {
                                                width: '41px'
                                            }
                                        }
                                     }">
                                </div>
                            </td>
```

[image]

How to hide the option id ="2"

Comment: can u please provide html code @Kapil

Comment: no need of jquery here you can do it on html side but for that you have to show your html code

Comment: Show your HTML code. unless it will go to off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Can you define a set of selectables for the values in the drop down and bind using ng-options, and remove an item from this when you initialise your form?

Answer (score 0):

I have Filtered the object something like below:

```
$scope.propertyType = $scope.propertyType.filter(function (e) { return e.id !== '2' })
```